# UIColor colorWithPatternImage changes the color of the image

Tags: ios, uicolor

I have the following code.

```
//Create a view to place repeated arrow in.
UIView *rootView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];

//Add Repeated Arrows to the top of the view using a color pattern.
UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-down"];
UIColor *repeatedArrowColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:arrowImage];
CGRect repeatedArrowFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, [arrowImage size].height);
UIView *repeatedArrowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:repeatedArrowFrame];
[repeatedArrowView setBackgroundColor:repeatedArrowColor];

[rootView addSubview:repeatedArrowView];
```

The image being used is a png with arrows colored #323232. I verified this by right clicking the .app file and selecting Show Package Contents.

[image: Image used to generate pattern.]

However when the pattern appears on the iOS simulator screen the color of the arrows are #262626 or #252525.

[image: Wrong colored arrows in the iOS simulator]

Has anyone run into this problem? If so, how did you fix, or did you work-around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short everyone has these problems. If you open that image in Preview and use pixie (dev tool), you will see a different value for the pixels than is in the file for sure. Is that value different from what you see in the Simulator?

Do your png's have a color profile embedded in them? It may help if there is one if you delete it (pngcrush will do this as an option). If there is none, or that does not fix it, then you may need to load your image first as a CGImageRef using:

```
CGImageRef CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider (
   CGDataProviderRef source,
   const CGFloat decode[],
   bool shouldInterpolate,
   CGColorRenderingIntent intent
);
```

and fool around with the color intent (first) and as a last option the decode array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've never ran into this problem before. Probably because I've either left Apple's Compress PNGs option on, or applied ImageOptim before using a png.

Comment: Just curious - how did you get the values you wanted?

Comment: Well, before you replied I had stopped using a png. Instead I draw a single arrow with CoreGraphics then use that as the basis for the pattern.

Comment: Nice! I do many things in my app by drawing and not using canned images.

Comment: Have you looked at PaintCode.app? Thought it would allow me to do in application drawing faster, but hasn't helped that much. Maybe I just don't know how to use it effectively yet.

Comment: Actually we did get a copy - used it once for something, but haven't used it a lot yet.