# Strange colorWithPatternImage on iPhone 5 hardware

Tags: iphone, objective-c, hardware

In a blank UIViewController, I change the screen color by:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackPattern.png"]];
```

Then I do a screen capture from my iPhone 5. The image looks like:

[image]

If you view the image in 100%, you'll see three bars (top, left and bottom). However, my pattern image is very simple (blackPattern@2x.png):

[image]

It's a 8x8 png for retina display.

Ironically, the bars are not visible when the app runs on the Simulator. Is it an iPhone 5 hardware specific symtom?

p.s. If you want to see it running, you may download my app: [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dead-spotter/id565048990?mt=8)

Comment: It looks fine to me. `colorWithPatternImage` takes your provided image and tiles it continuously to fill the background of the view. What is the specific issue you're having?

Comment: @Inspire48 didn't you notice the different patterns at left, top, and bottom parts of the image?

Comment: Are you seeing the bars on the iPhone itself? It looks perfectly uniform to me. I think I know why—I have a Retina MBP. It has the pixels to perfectly display the image. I do see discolored bars on a non-Retina display (connected to my rMBP via HDMI), however—the ones on the top and left are about a centimeter wide (although that will depend on the display), and the one at the bottom is 4 or 5 times wider. Is that what you're describing?

Comment: Yes, I can see the bottom bar on the iPhone. The left and top are less obvious on the iPhone. The bottom bar is 4 to 5 times thicker than the left and top. In fact, after an user who reported the issue then I noticed the strange pattern.

Comment: When you are using a pattern image you should use large image than 8 x 8. Try and see something like 120 x 120.

Comment: Here's another stackoverflow question that is similar to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393788/uicolor-colorwithpatternimage-changes-the-color-of-the-image. I wonder if you use pngcrush like David H suggests if that will fix your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. I can reproduce the problem on an iPhone 5 (not on simulator, not even in retina mode).

Some thoughts and observations: The color in the small patten image is exactly black and white  (0 and 255, each r, b and g). In the full screen image it's not. In the center it's 8 and 247, at the bottom 12, 243 and at the side 4, 251.

This very much looks like an interpolation artifact: When Core Graphics paints pixels from an image onto device pixels and the pixels do not match perfectly, it calculates interpolated colors from neighboring source pixels. Black and white would result in dark and bright grays: the effect we see in this case.

Still I don't know why this only happens on the device.

Playing a little bit with this problem I did not find the reason but a solution to your problem: Create the checkerboard pattern color yourself:

```
static void patternDrawPatternCallback(void *info, CGContextRef c)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; ++x) {
            CGFloat v = (x + y) & 1;
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, v, v, v, 1);
            CGContextFillRect(c, (CGRect){{x, y}, {1, 1}});
        }
    }
}

static void patternReleaseInfoCallback(void *info)
{
}

static UIColor *checkerColor()
{
    CGPatternCallbacks callbacks = {
        .drawPattern = patternDrawPatternCallback,
        .releaseInfo = patternReleaseInfoCallback,
    };

    CGFloat scale = 1.0f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGPatternRef pattern = CGPatternCreate(NULL,
                                           (CGRect){.size={8, 8}},
                                           CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale),
                                           8, 8,
                                           kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
                                           YES,
                                           &callbacks);

    CGFloat components[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreateWithPattern(colorspace, pattern, components);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGPatternRelease(pattern);

    UIColor *checkerColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:color];
    CGColorRelease(color);

    return checkerColor;
}
```

Using color from this code I was not able to reproduce the problem (even though I played with the pattern tiling and set the size of the tiles to be slightly off).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your exact problem, but this line:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackPattern.png"]];
```

... means you're using the file named "blackPattern.png" whether the device is retina or not. The line should be:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackPattern"]];
```

... (with no `.png` on the end). This way, your program will use "blackPattern.png" if non-retina and "blackPattern@2x.png" if the device is retina.

Probably, the simulator you're running this code on is non-retina so it looks fine; it's only a retina device that you see the problem.

Comment: That is not quite accurate; iOS will load the @2x even if you have the .PNG ending. Furthermore, "On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension." Whether you specify the .PNG ending or not doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Inspire48: I believe you're right, but I can't find any unambiguous reference that supports this. The class reference for [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) uses an extension-less filename example. Do you have a good link for this?

Comment: I suppose you could find a link, but a quick foray into Xcode will show that you can keep the extension and the system will still load the @2x graphics. You can tell by setting the Simulator to use the Retina device (under the Hardware menu).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating UIImageView or UIView and with transparent background. Since the image you are using contains both opaque and transparent colors, you can still see through it.

Comment: Why do you think is the pattern image transparent? Am I missing something?

Comment: Well it looks like the image can bee seen through. Does your checkered pattern contain transparent areas where the "white" would be?

Comment: No, the pattern image is completely opaque, yet I can reproduce the problem.